# Dynamic Cache Groups for CakePHP 3

Tags: caching, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have created a multi site application with Cakephp 3.5. So far I'm very happy with it but I have one particular problem. I would like keep certain cache groups at the site scope. For example if I want to clear products group for site 1 it should not clear the products for site 2.

I know I can have multiple config groups but this will not work for me because the number of sites is dynamic and new site can be created from admin panel on fly.

Is there a way to do it be extending cache engine?

Comment: There certainly is a way to handle this... however nobody here knows what exactly a "site" is in your apps context, so you probably won't get any good answers.

Comment: The site in my application represents a partition of data, in my example products. Client requests are passing Site-Key header to identify which partition to access. 90% of the responses are cached. I'm interested in finding out how I can purge cache group for a single partition?

Comment: Why wouldn't groups (or prefixes, and/or even custom cache names that incorporate the site key) work? You'd only work on one site at a time, wouldn't you? In that case configuring the cache on the fly should work fine, similarily you could setup the required cache config on the fly in the admin panel in case you need to target a specific site's cache.

Comment: I will try to use dynamic cache config as you've mentioned. Currently, all my cache config is added manually in app.php probably that's why I have problem with it. I've also noticed that too many groups per adapter create long cache keys and the memcache has a limit on the key length.

Comment: In that case try prefixes instead of groups.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to extend MemcachedEngine because I want to be able to change the prefix dynamically as needed. This can be useful for bulk edits like cloning products, etc.

The protected _key() method is a member of CacheEngine abstract class that is inherited by all engines.

The Site-Key is being added to app configuration by middleware that looks for a specific request headers.

I'm modifying the prefix as suggested by ndm in the comments.

```
class PrefixedMemcachedEngine extends MemcachedEngine
{
    private $_initCachePrefix = '';

    public function init(array $config = [])
    {
        $this->_initCachePrefix = $config['prefix'] ?? '';
        return parent::init($config);
    }

    protected function _key($key)
    {
        $this->_config['prefix'] = $this->_initCachePrefix . Configure::read('Site-Key');
        return parent::_key($key);
    }
}
```